# Why does OpenCV.js Mat.roi return sequential data instead of rectangular submat?

Tags: javascript, opencv

I'm using **Opencv.js** (specifically npm package `opencv-bindings`)
I'm trying to get a `roi` from a `mat`, but the method seems return wrong output.

- I define a **simple 3x3 array** filled with numbers 1..9
- Then I create ROI that starts at 1,1 and is of 2x2 size.
- The output I'm getting is as if the function started at 1,1 and returned 4 numbers sequentially from the starting point, wrapping to the next row.

I would expect to get
1 2 3
4 **5 6**
7 **8 9**

But I get
1 2 3
4 **5 6**
**7 8** 9

What am I doing wrong?

**Working repro:**
https://codesandbox.io/s/opencv-js-getting-started-with-images-adapted-forked-exqsxo?file=/src/index.js

**Code:**

```
const data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
const numMat = new cv.matFromArray(3, 3, cv.CV_8UC1, data);
console.log(numMat.data, numMat.cols, numMat.rows);
// 1 2 3
// 4 5 6
// 7 8 9

const numRoi = numMat.roi(new cv.Rect(1, 1, 2, 2));
console.log(numRoi.data, numRoi.cols, numRoi.rows);
// expect:
// 5 6
// 8 9

// get:
// 5 6
// 7 8
```